# Connecting to server that use mobile hot spot

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I have a client and server programs using sockets.
When the server sit on a local network the client connecting without problem.( external ip and port forward)
But when the computer that run the server is connected by mobile hot spot, the client cant reach the server.
I see that the external ip of the computer and the cellphone are the same and I understand that the local ip of the computer is 192.168.43.243
Is there a method to connect via the cell hot spot or it blocked by a NAT

server code :

```
Dim listener As New TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 8888)
listener.Start
While True
            Try
                client = listener.AcceptTcpClient()
 Catch

            End Try

        End While
```

client code

```
Dim clientSocket As TcpClient
Try
            clientSocket = New TcpClient(ipaAddress, port)
 End Try
```

Comment: By mobile hotspot, do you mean connected via Hotspot feature on a mobile phone? If so, that will route via the mobile network that the phone is connected to. That cannot give you the same public IP address as the local network.  Have you checked www.whatismyip.com on the PC when connected via the hotspot to confirm?

Comment: Thank you for respond. the computer is sitting on the mobile phone network and they have the same ipv4 ip address. I verified it by www.whatismyip.com . However the website finds the phone ipv6 address but not the ipv6 computer address. I did ipconfig on the computer and got this :Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2e43:fs67:efc0:39f%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.243
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1

Comment: Any IP address starting 192.168. is a private address NOT a public one.  While connected via the phone, the IP address of the computer will appear the same as the IP address of the phone to any external computers.

Comment: I know that the question what ip i need to give to the client socket. The share ip not succeed to connect